# Pie Graph not working as expected on PyPlot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

Running the following code gives me a NameError when i try to enter something(use) Please help.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

use = eval(input("Enter activites:"))
amount = eval(input("Amount:"))

plt.pie(amount, labels = use)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It's `use = input("Enter activites:")`. The eval does not make sense in this case.

Answer (score 0):

When using matplotlib, try to generate the graphs by using lists of values.

Try this for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

counter = 0
uses = list()
amounts = list()

while True:
    counter += 1
    use = input("Enter activity " + str(counter) + " (0 to finish): ")
    if use == "0":
        break
    else:
        uses.append(use)
        amount = eval(input("Enter amount for " + use + ": "))
        amounts.append(amount)

plt.pie(amounts, labels=uses)
plt.show()
```